# How does Azure know there has been a change to a database?

Tags: azure, integration

We're looking at using Azure for our integrations needs. We are currently doing a test where we want to make a change to a record in our on-premise erp(IFS10) in one ifs dev environment and see that change appear in another ifs dev environment.

Using Azure, how does it know when a change has been made and how does it replicate that change?

Hope that makes sense.

Thanks
Ross

Haven't tried anything to date.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're talking about transaction replication. Under the hood the 'master' will write to a change log, and the 'reader' will use the concept of watermark to filter/detect if there are new/changed items.

More information about it: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/managed-instance/replication-transactional-overview?view=azuresql

There are other ways to achieve too, you can leverage Azure Functions with the SQL Binding, you can use some Change Data Capture tool such as Debezium.